# How to save a Python Dictionary as a Pickle object on AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary, amazon-s3, pickle

I have a python dictionary. I want to save it as a pickle object in AWS S3.

I am trying this -

```
import boto3
import pickle


#Connect to S3 default profile
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

serializedMyData = pickle.dumps(myDictionary)

s3.put_object(Bucket='mytestbucket',Key='myDictionary')
```

The script runs successfully and I get a file with name * myDictionary* in the S3. But it is not a pickle and it has 0 bytes.

I edited my code a little bit -

```
import boto3
import pickle


#Connect to S3 default profile
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

serializedMyData = pickle.dumps(myDictionary)

s3.put_object(Bucket='mytestbucket',Key='myDictionary').put(Body=serializedMyData)
```

But then I get this error -

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'put'
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `s3.put_object(Bucket='mytestbucket',Key='myDictionary', Body=serializedMyData)`

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-put_object.py.html

Comment: When I add serializedMyData I get the error - 
TypeError: put_object() only accepts keyword arguments.

Comment: fixed answer, don't know why my comment on this vanished